# What parameter do I use after the .equals function to make the example test pass?

Tags: java

Why does

```
public class CodePair {
    /* Attribute Declarations */

    private char c;
    private String code;

    /* Constructor initializes the character and code
     *  in the pair 
     */
    public CodePair(char c, String code) {
        this.c = c;
        this.code = code;       
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public char getCharacter() {
        return this.c;
    }

    /**
     * setCharacter method sets the CodePairs character value
     * @param c
     */

    public void setCharacter(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    /**
     * setCode method sets the CodePairs code value
     * @param code
     */

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     * equals determines whether two CodePairs have the same character value
     * @param anotherPair other CodePair object that this is compared to
     * @return true if they have the same character
     */

    public boolean equals (CodePair anotherPair) {  
    if (this.c == anotherPair.c)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

    }

}





public class ArrayCode {
    /* Attribute Declarations */


    private CodePair[] codeList;
    private int numPairs;

    /* Constructor */

    public ArrayCode (int size) {
        codeList = new CodePair[size];
        numPairs = 0;

    }

    public void add (CodePair pair) {
        if(numPairs == codeList.length)
            expandCapacity();   
        codeList[numPairs] = pair;
        numPairs++;

    }

    private void expandCapacity() {
        if(codeList.length <= 100) {
            CodePair[] largerList = new CodePair[codeList.length*2];
            for(int i = 0; i <codeList.length; i++)
                largerList[i] = codeList[i];            
            codeList = largerList;
        }

        else {
            CodePair[] largerList = new CodePair[codeList.length + 20];
            for(int i = 0; i <codeList.length; i++)
                largerList[i] = codeList[i];        
            codeList = largerList;

        }   

    }

    private void reduceCapacity() {
        if((numPairs*4)<codeList.length) {
            CodePair[] smallerList = new CodePair[codeList.length/2];
            for(int i = 0; i <codeList.length; i++)
                smallerList[i] = codeList[i];
            codeList = smallerList; 
        }
    }

    public void remove(CodePair pairToRemove) {
        int i = 0;
        while ((i<numPairs) && !codeList[i].equals(pairToRemove)) {
            i++;
        }
        if(i != numPairs) {
            codeList[i] = codeList[numPairs - 1];
            codeList[numPairs - 1] = null;
            numPairs --;
            reduceCapacity();

        }       
    }

    public int findCode(String code) {

        int i = 0;
        while ((i<numPairs) && !codeList[i].equals(code)) {
            i++;
        }
        if(codeList[i].equals(code)) {
            return i;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public int findCharacter(char c) {

        int i = 0;
        while ((i<numPairs) && !codeList[i].equals(c)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (codeList[i].equals(c)) {
            return i;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public String getCode(int i) {

        if(i < 0 || i >= numPairs) {

        return null;
        }
        else {
            return codeList[i].getCode();
        }
    }

    public char getCharacter(int i) {

        if (i < 0 || i >= numPairs) {

            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return codeList[i].getCharacter();
        }   
    }

    public int getSize() {

        return codeList.length;

    }

    public int getNumPairs() {

        return numPairs;
    }   
}
```

this code not work with this test? I think it has something to do with my .equals parameter as well as the return (not sure if it should just be i) but I'm pretty stumped as to why it isn't working. Have I declared variables incorrectly? Any help at all would be highly appreciated, I'm very new to Java so there are probably really dumb and obvious mistakes. I think I've also messed up the constructor in the ArrayCode class somehow, and that could be why most of the methods aren't working/doing what they are supposed to do.

Both classes are in separate files but I've pasted them together in the post so it's easier to see. There are other tests also failing but I think if I can solve this one it will help point me in the right direction to solve the others as well.

```
Test:

try {
    test = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    if (list.findCharacter((char)i) != (i-1)) test = false;
    if (list.findCode(Integer.toBinaryString(i)) != (i-1)) test = false;
    }

    if (test) System.out.println("Test 3 passed");
    else System.out.println("Test 3 failed");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Test 3 failed");
}
```

Test 2 that fails:

```
try {
    test = true;
    list.remove(new CodePair((char)10,"1010"));
    if (list.findCode("1010") != -1 || list.findCharacter((char)10) != -1)
    test = false;

    if (list.getSize() != 20 || list.getNumPairs() != 19) test = false;

    if (test) System.out.println("Test 5 passed");
    else System.out.println("Test 5 failed");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Test 5 failed");
}
```

Comment: Is the issue somehow related to not declaring c as a CodePair object? Eclipse seems to think so

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The first snippet is missing a class. The second snippet is missing both a class and a method.

Comment: Not enough context - show the complete code.

Comment: I can't actually add the test to the post because it adds too much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an object of type `CodePair` to both `char`s and `String`s. However, you haven't overriden `.equals(Object)`, so the call delegates to `==`, which is always false for different types. I think you meant to compare the fields of the `CodePair` object in both cases. This can be done as follows:

```
codeList[i].getCode().equals(code); // Strings compared by .equals()

codeList[i].getCharacter() == c; // Primitive chars compared by ==
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! And your explanation was very helpful I really appreciate it!

Comment: If I can ask one more question without opening a new thread, what's going on with my add and remove functions because I don't think they are working correctly.

Comment: Just from looking at them, `add` looks like it should work. `remove` changes the order by moving the last `CodePair` to the position of the one you're removing, which might cause unexpected results as the `getCode` and `getCharacter` methods access the array by index. I would expect a `remove` method to shift all elements after the one being removed down one index.

Comment: OK and the getSize and getNumPairs methods are OK? I think the getSize one isn't working properly and it's throwing off one of the other tests

Comment: Well, the names are a bit misleading. `getSize` returns the capacity and `getNumPairs` returns the number of actual elements, which I would see as the size. Do the tests expect this behaviour?

Comment: That behaviour is expected. getSize should return a higher number than getNumPairs in almost all cases.

I've updated the original post with the test in question

Comment: It's almost certainly the remove function that is doing something incorrectly

Comment: Your `equals` method is fishy. It only compares one of two fields. This means the `remove` method will remove the first `CodePair` which has the same `c` value as the one you pass. Without the data you're putting in before running the tests, it's difficult to tell exactly what's happening. It could be that multiple `CodePair`s have the same `c` value but you only remove one, or that the expected behaviour involves the `code` field as well. Try doing some debugging and tracking down where exactly your code deviates from what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Char is a primitive type, use ‘==‘ instead.

codeList[i] == c

Comment: `codeList` is a `CodePair[]`, so this will cause an incompatible types compile-time error.